# Maven Projects Side Bar

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just installed the community edition v13. What has happened to the side bar to the right which had the maven projects. With one click it would display the maven projects. When I go to View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects it displays but when I hide it, it completely disappears. It didn't do this in version 12. It's annoying to keep going to the top menu bar. Any ideas on how to get it back?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific feature of a version of a product rather than about a programming problem.

Comment: Off-topic from what basis? That's why I tagged it with the intellij tag only. Only people interested in that tag should have picked it up.

Comment: But the solving of problem helps to programmer to work more effective, isn't it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Idea 13, in left-right part are by default invisible(to not use place). Click on showed button to go to previous style.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also was angry with it before finded :)))